# JavaScript libraries use codes that are not supported by current browsers

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JS, and I even do not know a lot about it, there are different version of it and I'm really confused, ECMA-262, ES 5, ES 6 ... and V8

And I know there are some new features added in newer versions, like defining class by `class` keyword.

I looked at bunch of libraries at GitHub, most of famous libraries are using keywords like `import` or `let` that is not supporting by current browsers which many people are using, but they are still using those keywords *(which means ES 5 or ES 6)*

And almost all of those libraries have a version for browsers.

**What is the current version of JavaScript we mostly use?**

**How those libraries, convert their codes which has been written in ES 6 to the version that is supported by current browsers?** *(Most of those libraries have a version for browsers named `library.min.js`)*

**Why do they use those keywords when most of browsers are not supporting them?**

Comment: This is what babel does, it compiles ES6 into ES5 (which all browsers support). JFGI

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Does it mean, now people write codes in ES6 and convert it to ES5 using bebel?

Comment: Yup, just open https://babeljs.io/

Comment: Pretty much every browser supports ES5. The only common browsers that don't handle at least all the main features of ES6 are IE<11. And note that V8 is not a version of JS, it's a JS engine. Note that there are a number of libraries on GitHub intended for use in server-side JS, and if you're running server-side JS you have control over which version of JS you can use.

Comment: @nnnnnn But there are GitHub repositories that uses ES6 and are for client side, and they use `import` keyword which mean they need to import some files (And it is from ES 6), how to convert a GitHub repository to ES 5? Does Babel also do that?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly But there are GitHub repositories that uses ES6 and are for client side, and they use import keyword which mean they need to import some files (And it is from ES 6), how to convert a GitHub repository to ES 5? Does Babel also do that?

Comment: Go read documentation first, all answers are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Mostly we use javascript in common browser using ES 5 or ECMA-262 (Now is 2016)
- They use Babel https://babeljs.io/ to run the next standard JS in ES 6 or ECMAScript 2015

**[@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn)**: Now in 2016 every browser supports ES5. The only common browsers that don't handle at least all the main features of ES6 are IE<11. And note that V8 is not a version of JS, it's a JS engine. Note that there are a number of libraries on GitHub intended for use in server-side JS, and if you're running server-side JS you have control over which version of JS you can use.

Comment: Your answer worked well